# How to declare a contravariant function member in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, subclass, covariant, contravariant

I have a class that contains a member that is a function that takes an instance of the class:

```ts
class Super {
    public member: (x: Super) => void = function(){}
    use() {const f = this.member; f(this)}
}
```

but I want member to be contravariant; specifically, I want to allow subclass instances to accept `member` values that are functions that take that specific subclass, i.e.:

```ts
class Sub extends Super {
    method() {}
}

const sub = new Sub();
sub.member = function(x: Sub) {x.method()};
```

but tsc quite correctly complains:

```
Type '(x: Sub) => void' is not assignable to type '(x: Super) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
    Property 'method' is missing in type 'Super' but required in type 'Sub'.
```

How do I declare `member` such that it can in subclasses be a function that takes a covariant (rather than contravariant) parameter type?

---

What I've tried:

- I know that if I declare `member` using method syntax (`member(s: Super) {/* ... */}`) then it will be bivariant, but this does not help in situations where `member` might be a collection of functions (e.g., in my actual code the type of `member` is a dictionary of such functions: `{[name: string]: (/*...*/, s: Super) => /*...*/}`).
- I attempted to redeclare `member` in `Sub` with a more restrictive signature:

  ```ts
  class Sub extends Super {
      public member: (x: Sub) => void = function(x){x.method()};
      method() {}
  }
  ```

  but tsc steadfastly refuses to let me aim the gun at my foot:

  ```
  Property 'member' in type 'Sub' is not assignable to the same property in base type 
  'Super'.
    Type '(x: Sub) => void' is not assignable to type '(x: Super) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
        Property 'method' is missing in type 'Super' but required in type 'Sub'.
  ```
- I understand that [typescript now supports `in` and `out` modifiers on templates to denote co/contravariance](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/14442) but I am not sure if they are applicable nor how to turn `Super` into a suitably-templated declaration.
- I'd rather not turn off `strictfunctionTypes`, as it is generally useful and I don't want to force users of this library to turn it off in order to assign to `.member` on subclass instances.
- As a last resort I can just cast the values being assigned to `as (x: Super) => void`,
  but this removes protection against assigning to the wrong subclass, e.g.:

  ```ts
  class Sub1 extends Super {
      method1() {}
  }
  class Sub2 extends Super {
      method2() {}
  }

  const sub1 = new Sub1();
  sub1.member = function(x: Sub2) {x.method2()} as (x: Super) => void;
  ```

  is accepted by tsc but fails at runtime.
- Checking the related questions, I see [a similar question involving interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74257423/typescript-contravariance-issue-with-map-of-functions) rather than subclasses, but it has no formal answers yet and I do not fully understand the snippets linked in the comments; they appear to depend on being able to fully enumerate all of the subtypes, which is not suitable for my situation where there may be an arbitrary number of (sub)*subclasses.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPBaeN)?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz: I think such an answer would be useful to others reading this question, but alas in my actual code the `this` value passed when calling `member` is already bound to another value, and must remain so for backward-compatibility reasons.  [Edit: it is possible that I have not understood what you have in mind; a write-up would be most welcome.]

Comment: Given that such a requirement isn't in the question, what should we do here?  I imagine you could either [edit] the question to specify that this is not viable, or you could leave it alone, accept a polymorphic-`this` answer, and then open a new question with your added constraints.  Which of those do you want to do? ... [Responding to edit: can you test my suggestion in your code and get back to me then?  Either it works (yay) or it doesn't (and we fall back to my question before the edit)]

Comment: OK, my previous mumblings about the binding of `this` were definitely confused.  The example of using the `this` type given in your playground example works for me (bar a strange oddity about which I will post a separate question).  Happy to accept a writeup if you'd like the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might want the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), which acts like an implicit [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter that is always constrained to the "current" class.  So inside the `Super` class body, the `this` type refers to "some subtype of `Super`", while inside the `Sub` class body it refers to "some subtype of `Sub`".  For *instances* of `Super`, the `this` type will be instantiated with `Super`, and for `Sub` it will be instantiated with `Sub`.

That is, inside the class body, `this` acts like a generic parameter, and outside the class body it behaves like that parameter has been specified with a type argument corresponding to the current object type.

---

That gives you the desired behavior with your example code:

```
class Super {
    public member: (x: this) => void = function () { } 
    use() { const f = this.member; f(this) }
}


class Sub extends Super {
    method() { }
}

const sub = new Sub();
sub.member = function (x: Sub) { x.method() }; // okay
```

Looks good.

---

Note that you could simulate this behavior by using generics *explicitly* (using a [recursive, F-bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) constraint reminiscent of Java):

```
class Super<T extends Super<T>> { 
    public member: (x: T) => void = function () { }
    use(this: T) { const f = this.member; f(this) } 
}

class Sub extends Super<Sub> {
    method() { }
}

const sub = new Sub();
sub.member = function (x: Sub) { x.method() };
```

which is less pretty but gives you some more flexibility, if `this` types by themselves don't meet your needs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVAFgSyignjZA3gFBKlLwA2IUUSAygK74BOSxZHSMDARhRvCSQwPCMwBcSABQAPSQBdMUAJRIAvAD4kANwD2GACbqkAMwbB48jLuDTVBJAF8SnUgygQp98jajzTxopYAHTCoswA3KZSQSpOLqTORAnkVDT0vEgQMvIQwAa0jCxsKRyQiroGXmzxHEkc8L7+UJlqSMAQAO4ZPF4RKS08oRAiYsZmFlY20nI93jLDFVWqjv1JoJCwCMgA4nliAiUplNSFTGIAPChZOXkFGSxXWm1FlyDAOBpa7K5cvPyCMJiSSySQoVSaHT6IxtCaWay2aoOZy-JDuTyxMHeRrAPwBNqxYajSLRWIrFL1MgndKMHg3XL5M6PWnfUpkcpoSpI2pkSmkHF4wbGDrdWl9Aa8InhcbmeHTUFzGoLDlclb9ZKOIA)