# Why is the type {[x: string]: this} not equivalent to Record<string, this> in TypeScript class member declarations?

Tags: typescript, language-lawyer, typescript-generics, free-variable

#### Background

Last week I asked [a question about how to declare a class member that is a function whose parameter is covariant with the class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77150148/4969945), for which [using the polymorphic `this` type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77152472/4969945) was a perfect solution.

My actual code has a class with a member which is a dictionary of such functions.  In adapting the solution, ran in to an unexpected type error.

#### Question

Given [the following class declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC0G8BQ1XQA4FcBGICWw0AtgKZHYkBOAXNAC4AWeEA3CmlrgdBCXbQGU+AHkbMAfNAC80AHYkA7tCF0AFAEoWabagD0u6AHkA0u1Sd8hACYE6ARloIA2gA9aEOpTyyA5gF1aMQgAX2lEYK00fWgAUUpKAHsaaABBaAByIPT6AE90EmhmaDAANzA8cFwChNkQHMLZYrkagFoPMDpuUnIqaASAMybQSBgkhroqfrBgEgA6MwwcS2gbYDoAJloAJRJgJKthDy9fABp6JghJGQQIqIMTBYtuVboAZkcnAAUGnk9vf0CF1C11u0GiJgA-ABCJALPayI6YNZjDSIIKzboUShhIIsYJIfFAA):

```ts
class C {
    public dict1: {[x: string]: this} = {};    // Error: A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface.
    public dict2: Record<string, this> = {};   // OK
    public dict3: {[P in string]: this} = {};  // OK?!
}
```

Why does the declaration of `dict1`, using an index signature, provoke the error

> A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface

but the seemingly-equivalent declarations of `dict2` (using the `Record<>` utility type), and `dict3` (using a different index signature based on [the definition of Record<>](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f3dad2a07d007c40d260f13d6b087a2d5685d12d/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1579)) not provoke the same error?

Comment: Please [edit] to ask a single question, to avoid this being closed as needing focus. Your 1&2 might plausibly be asked as part of a single question, but 3 is essentially different.  Which one should we focus on?

Comment: If you pick 1&2, the answer is that `this` is prohibited in a type where it's ambiguous what it refers to (in `interface X {a: {b: this}}`, does `this` refer to `X` or to `X["a"]`?)  and any indirection which clears this up will be allowed.  If you pick 3, that's just a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and is well documented.  I'd be happy to flesh one of these into an answer but not both, so please do [edit] the question when you get a chance and/or let me know how to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz: Thanks for the advice.  I did indeed have at least two questions, but I have rewritten it to focus on just one of them, though still referencing all three examples.  (For posterity: the original question 3 which you have helpfully answered in your comment was "what's up with `P` (here and in the definition of Record<>)?".)

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer for the current version of the question when I get a chance; probably at least three hours from now.

Answer (score 1):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#47868](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47868) for a canonical answer to most of this question.  The [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#4910](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910), generally refers to the type of [the `this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) *in the scope in which it is mentioned*.  For a type like

```
interface Foo { a: this }
```

`this` refers to a `Foo` or some subtype of `Foo`, so you could implement it like

```
class Bar implements Foo { a = this; }
class Baz extends Bar { z = "abc" }
const baz = new Baz();
console.log(baz.a.a.a.z.toUpperCase()); // "ABC"
```

So `baz`, `baz.a`, `baz.a.a`, etc. are all of type `Baz`. That's great.

But for a type like

```
interface Qux { a: { b: this } } // error!
// -------------------> ~~~~
// only in an interface property or a class instance member
```

*what does `this` refer to*?  What's the relevant scope? One could possibly expect it to refer to the outer scope, and therefore it's `Qux` (or a subtype), but maybe it refers to just the inner scope and thus it's `Qux["a"]` (or a subtype).  It's ambiguous.

TypeScript sidesteps the ambiguity by only allowing `this` to be used in an interface property or a class instance member, with no intervening scopes.  That's why the above is an error.

In order to specify which one you mean, you have to use some indirection, possibly with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  If you want the outer scope, you can do this:

```
interface B<T> { b: T }
interface Qux { a: B<this> }
```

Now `this` can only refer to a subtype of `Qux`.  You can implement it with a class like

```
class Quux implements Qux {
    a = { b: this }
    z = "abc";
}
const q = new Quux();
console.log(q.a.b.a.b.z.toUpperCase()) // "ABC"
```

So `q`, `q.a.b`, `q.a.b.a.b`, etc, are all of type `Quux`.

If you want the inner scope, you can do this:

```
interface B { b: this }
interface Qux { a: B }
```

Now `this` can only refer to a subtype of `B`.  You can implement it like

```
class Quux implements Qux {
    a = { get b() { return this }, z: "abc" };
}
const q = new Quux();
console.log(q.a.b.b.b.z.toUpperCase()) // "ABC"
```

Here I've used a getter but you could do it with another class if you want.  Anyway now `q.a`, `q.a.b`, `q.a.b.b`, etc, are of type `Quux["a"]`.

---

For your example,

```
class C {
    dict: { [x: string]: this } = {};
}
```

you've got an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), which behaves like a *range* of keys in an object type.  An index signature can sit alongside other properties in an object type (e.g., `{[k: string]: string; foo: "bar"}`).

And `{ [x: string]: this }` is just as ambiguous as `{ a: this }`.  Does `this` refer to an instance of `C` or just to an the `dict` property of `C`?  It looks like you intended the former.  Thus we need some kind of indirection.  You could do so like

```
type Dict<T> = { [x: string]: T };
class C {
    dict: Dict<this> = {}; // okay
}
```

But of course you don't have to write your own `Dict` type.  The [`Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) can be pressed into service this way, where `Record<string, T>` is essentially the same thing:

```
class C {
    dict: Record<string, this> = {}; // okay
}
```

And finally, if you define a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) inline like

```
class C {
    dict: { [K in string]: this } = {}; // okay
}
```

it also works, because apparently *a mapped type does not introduce its own scope*.  Note that while the syntax for mapped types looks similar to that of index signatures, *they are not the same*.  (The question refers to this as an index signature, but it is not an index signature.)  An index signature can be thought of a piece of an object type (e.g., other properties and signatures can appear inside an object type with it), while a mapped type is its own separate thing (e.g., the curly braces are part of the mapped type; you can't add other properties).  See [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331699/2887218) for more about that.

---

So there you go.  You can only use polymorphic `this` in a place where the scope is not ambiguous according to the compiler.  You can't do it inside a nested object property, or an index signature, but you *can* do it with indirection, generics, and apparently mapped types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQDED2nUG9UIBcqEAFiAM6oC+wSANghVQEIIyogC2ADvVFyiQqWHPgSoAvCXIUA3DTqNmqNgC9UUAB7QwAE1bs8qDdIBECAEZIzipJjAUIqSwlOowUAO6q3ACgBKOToHCkx+ADp6TABzP1c1CIQklMSITABVHh5YAGEmKECg1AB6EtQzAEEWXLNgevBoeGQ0AEUAVy1jImNLYjJKGkUyzRgYTBhiMExnBDBOSFhEFFQecZyYCABPVAmCVAYmKnAnOZXBLktYVHqwBEEKHhbUAHl2prxgVG+FpuW0FgAHgAKgA+XrEYGKH6-JbPDpdcTEIEDCjg2gww4qDqdTi8fiCYSoBGfGEwiTSfB9GSDDFk77uCzWMzBGF0772RzOACOUg83mJ7U6gVZP05YUi0Ti3JSlllETSmWyeQKRVK5SqNTqtFu9ygj2eAEkwJ4OLgvj9GnCViwITSqOzYc0ViSkapoWLlFQcV1uHwBEIIN7ceb6d8KcYYlBnJZAsYYNH2jB5qiaAAaEzEJk2Gii76O8U8vmeHw+kUWjmhcJQKKxPwy5JypsKiLpLIbfIUQoBALqirVWr1HXAbY5VAAERASAgIPBlNQAG0tMQnDBwDEALqQ3P1LFUXJsPSkn48dqWehT1B6KcQYj4JcriBrsCb-qyIaU6gKH4jACiYwmYhKlQAByVEQJILYx0GBAADcEBARhzzQBx6B2cB9mmMAAFpTggS8LiuDhMDgfY912DgrWdGtgB1cjcmPb5T3PS9r2nYhJ2nQFUTnPAvxhP8AMmVBgLA2QINHNAYPgxCrH4XYwDQhZMIcXCIAQfCkFQQjrhIsivQop1-giWjdwM3IAHFsCPUMTzPC8tLY29UAAJSgewYD0QFV3XDMeL5XBaDo8zKnoMIrMwGyK1WezWJvO9FwAaWUnyXy3e0P26N9aVooA)